Type assertion does not narrow class instance from union
Since type narrowing works in so many other cases I expected an instance method to also narrow the type of this like the type annotations would seem to suggest, but this only works in other methods on the same type, not outside the class. Is there another way to make the instance method assertion work or do I just need to resign myself to exporting helper assert functions?
  class box<T> {
    constructor(public value: T){}

    check(): this is box<string> {
      return typeof this.value == 'string';
    }

    assert(): asserts this is box<string> {
      if (typeof this.value != 'string') throw new Error();
    }

    private test() {
      this.assert();
      // type correctly narrowed
      this.value.substring(0);
    }
  }

  function make() : box<string> | box<number> {
    return new box('a');
  }

  function assert(b: box<string> | box<number>): asserts b is box<string> {
    if (typeof b.value != 'string') throw new Error();
  }

  const b = make();

  if (b.check()) {
    // type correctly narrowed
    b.value.substring(0);
  }

  b.assert();

  // type not narrowed (substring does not exist on type 'string | number')
  b.value.substring(0);
   
  assert(b);

  // type correctly narrowed
  b.value.substring(0);


Looks like unions of assertion function signatures do not act as assertion function signatures, as shown in this playground link. I don't see an existing GitHub issue about it so if you want to file one to see what they say it could be worthwhile. Then when they triage it you could come back here and write an answer.
